# How to start merged .NET application?

Tags: .net

So, I use ILMerge to merge my .NET assemblies to one. Basically, the one .NET application is the core, the console and the other .NET application is a GUI,  the front-end. Now, the GUI calls up the console-application and passes the arguments to it. Done. But now I merged my console-application into my GUI application. How would I now call my console-application, which is now merged with the GUI, in my GUI application code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just call the `Main` method of the console code:

```
public class GuiApp
{
    public void WhenYouWantToCallTheConsole()
    {
        // Probably in a different thread...
        ConsoleApp.Main(...);
    }
}

public class ConsoleApp
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, this will run the console app *in the same process* - whereas previously presumably you started it as a separate process. In many cases this is fine, but you need to be aware of it as a difference.

Comment: Mh, wait. When I now try to call the application, wouldn't it tell me that ConsoleApp.Main() doesn't exist as the GUI code itself does not yet include the references, method names, etc. of my console application?

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: Ah - well, you could call it by reflection... but wouldn't it be easier just to add a reference?

Comment: I just did add a reference. Yes, it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: One remaining question. The console app now is running internally in my GUI application, exactly as I wanted. However, how would I open a console command line internally from my GUI application? Because my console application displays important output. With the merge, no console application opens anymore (the console application still runs internally in the background) and now I can't see the console output. Is there any way to open up a command line for this and redirect the output to it?

Comment: @Tetragrammaton: Not very easily, no. But you could use `Console.SetOut` and provide a writer to catch the output, and then display that wherever you want.